# Correctness of Proof and Use of Axiom of Choice (Analysis I by Terence Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-theory, cardinals

I've skipped over some of the references in my proof for brevity. The following is an exercise from Terence Tao's Analysis I, specifically section 8.1. on countablity. ("countable" here refers to "countably infinte").

---

**Exercise 8.1.9.** Suppose that $I$ is an at most countable set, and for each $\alpha \in I$, let $A_\alpha$ be an at most countable set. Show that the set $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha$ is also at most countable. In particular, countable unions of countable sets are countable. (This exercise requires the axiom of choice, see Section 8.4).

*Proof.* Suppose $I$ is an at most countable set, and for each $\alpha \in I$ let $A_\alpha$ be an at most countable set.

We can construct injective functions $f\colon I \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g_\alpha\colon A_\alpha \to \mathbb{N}$, since we can either construct a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$ (countable, Defn 8.1.1) or to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ specifically $\{i\in \mathbb{N}\mid 1\leq i \leq n\}$ for some finite cardinality $n$ (finite, Defin 3.6.5).

For all $x\in \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} A_\alpha \right)$, we know we have some $\alpha \in I$ s.t. $x\in A_\alpha$ (Axiom of Union) hence the set $\{\alpha \in I \mid x \in A_\alpha\}$ is non-empty. Thus, $\min f(\{\alpha \in I \mid x \in A_\alpha\}$ exists and is unique (Well orderng principle), and is within the range of $f$. Hence we have a function $\beta\colon \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha \to I$ s.t. $\beta(x) = f^{-1} \big(\min f(\{\alpha \in I \mid x \in A_\alpha\}\big)$ where $x\in A_{\beta(x)}$.

Let $h\colon \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha\to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ be defined by $h(x) = \Big(f\big(\beta(x)\big), g_{\beta(x)}(x)\Big)$. $h$ can be shown to be injective since $f$ and $g_{\beta(x)}$ are injective (skipped over for brevity). $h\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha\right)$ is at most countable since it is the subset of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ (Corollary 8.1.7), where $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is countable (Corollary 8.1.13). Hence, since $h$ is injective, $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ is also at most countable. $\square$

---

Tao hasn't gone over the Axiom of Choice yet in the book, so I'm not exactly sure what it specifically entails. However, if such axiom is required, it should be apparent from what I know that I am making some leap of logic. I'm not sure what that is, I'm suspicous it has something to do with the construction of $\beta$ which is used to find some unique $\alpha\in I$ for any $x$ s.t. $x\in A_\alpha$. Or perhaps even though $g_\alpha$ *exists*, it probably requires Axiom of Choice to choose such $g_\alpha$ for potentially infinite $\alpha$. Note: Here I use Well ordering principle specifically for natural numbers which I believe doesn't need Axiom of Choice.

I'm also not 100% sure my proof is correct, so some review there would be appreciated.

Comment: For each $\alpha\in I$ you are selecting one element $g_{\alpha}$ from the (infinite) set of all injective functions from $A_{\alpha}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. That uses the Axiom of Choice when $I$ is infinite.

Comment: @Sam I think it is valid to say for all $\alpha \in I$ we can select the injective function $g_\alpha$. I think the specific problem was that I used $g_{\beta(x)}$ later in the proof, I was implicitly implying that I had actually constructed some choice function $\alpha \mapsto g_\alpha$ which of course requires the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: The statement "we can select the injective function $g_\alpha$" is valid only if you assume the Axiom of Choice. Without it, all you can say is that the set of all injective functions from $A_\alpha$  to $\mathbb{N}$ is not empty.

Comment: @Sam I'm not convinced. We know (1) $\forall \alpha \in I$, $A_\alpha$ is a countable set, and (2) For all at most countable sets $X$, there exists an injective function $g\colon X\to \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, with (1) and (2) using rules of inferences, $\forall \alpha \in I$ there exists an injective function $g\colon A_\alpha\to \mathbb{N}$. I suppose "select" was a poor term here, although in the original post, I said "construct" merely because I used existential instantiation and then used that to construct a new function. So it's still just the existential statement (2).

Comment: This seems to be what you agree with, since you mentioned that the set of all injective functions from $A_\alpha$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is non-empty. So like I said, it's mainly just later in the proof when I implicitly meant $\alpha \mapsto g_\alpha$ to be a function, rather than just an existential statement.

Comment: We're on the same page.